# React and Rails Devise Signout Not Working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise, routes

I am using React + Rails for a web-app, and am using Devise for users authentication. I am struggling with getting a custom Logout button to work.

In my routes.rb I have the following:

```
devise_for :users do
  delete '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' #I've also tried get instead of delete
end
```

My devise.rb is configured as follows:

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

In my (React) JS .jsx file, I have the following logout function, called when the button is clicked.

```
function logout() {
    fetch("/users/sign_out", {method: 'delete'}).then((response) => { #I have also tried replacing delete with get
   }).then((result) => {
     window.location.href = '/';
   });
}
```

When I use fetch + delete, I get get a 422 error from the fetch; when I use fetch + get, I get a 404 error from the fetch. I've experimented with the various possible permutations of get/delete across the routes/devise.rb files and the .jsx file with no luck.

Specifically, from my rails console I see the following for the 422 error:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity. Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

My application controller has the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Interestingly, if I make it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    protect_from_forgery prepend: true
    before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Then the 422 error goes away (but the application still acts as if the user is logged in).

Comment: whats the error you are getting when you use fetch+delete?

Comment: What do you have in rails server log with `method: 'delete'`?

Comment: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Comment: @biocompamateur, great! And what are you doing with CSRF tokens on other devise actions?

Comment: I'm not really doing anything with CSRF tokens (other than what's being done with builtin devise functionality)

Comment: @biocompamateur, OK, do you sign up users with devise? Does it work well? Do you have a line with `protect_from_forgery` somewhere in your controllers and which value it has?

Comment: Yes, updating post

Comment: For now, I was able to get everything working by changing things from deletes to gets. Not sure why this helped, and am hoping to get it to work with delete functionality.

Comment: Did you import `@rails/ujs`?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same stack (redux/rails) , im getting a 201, not sure if its correct yet, but maybe this function will help you for the CRSF token:

```
    export const getMetaContent = (name) => {
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
      if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == name) {
        return metas[i].getAttribute("content");
      }
    }
}
// credit : https://labs.chiedo.com/post/authenticating-your-reactjs-app-with-devise-no-extra-gems-needed/
```

And then my Delete request in my saga for /users/signout looks like this:

```
  logoutUser = () => {
    console.log("CHIIII");
    const url = "users/sign_out.json";
    const options = {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        authenticity_token: getMetaContent("csrf-token")
      }
    }
      fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
```